# Dictionary<string, Action<T1,T2>>, where T's are Lists<>?

Tags: c#

Can a dictionary hold methods (`Action<>`), where those methods receive two parameters that are `List<>`?

I get multiple this error when I try the code below: `The dictionary is not compiling:"using the generic type Dictionary<> requires two parameters" "Invalid expression term 'string'" "; expected"...`

```
Dictionary<string, Action<List<Data_Raw>,List<Data_Result>> rulesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Action> { };
        rulesDictionary.Add("twentyFifty", CTARules.TwentyFiftyMA);
        rulesDictionary.Add("twentyHundred", CTARules.TwentyHundredMA);

public class Data_Raw
{

}

class Data_Result
{
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the errors you are receiving. This code won't compile as is, since it lacks definitions of `Data_Raw` and `Data_Result`. See [mcve] for more on what we'd like to see a question like this include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors like missing closing angle brackets `>` and using the wrong types on your dictionary constructor.

Here is a complete working mcve, [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9prS9D)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, Action<List<Data_Raw>, List<Data_Result>>> rulesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Action<List<Data_Raw>, List<Data_Result>>>();
        rulesDictionary.Add("twentyFifty", CTARules.TwentyFiftyMA);
    }
}

class Data_Raw
{
}

class Data_Result
{
}

class CTARules
{
    public static void TwentyFiftyMA(List<Data_Raw> myRawData, List<Data_Result> myResultData)
    {
    //do stuff
    }

    public static void TwentyHundredMA(List<Data_Raw> myRawData, List<Data_Result> myResultData)
    {
    //do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Dictionary<string, Action<List<Data_Raw>,List<Data_Result>>>` can't be instantiated as `Dictionary<string, Action>` - you should instantiate the exact type you need.
Also, this is classic for using the `var` keyword:

```
var rulesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Action<List<Data_Raw>,List<Data_Result>>>();
```

Comment: please explain your comment on using var

Comment: There are basically two good situations to declare your local variables using the `var` keyword instead of an explicit type - one is when you are using an anonymous type (and then you *have to* use `var`), and the other is when you are initializing that variable in the same line of code - it's not obligatory but it does make your code shorter and more readable. Of course, the longer the type name is, the more effective the use of `var` is.